# Is there a way to turn off Facebook’s spammy page notifications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-notifications

I manage several low-volume Pages on Facebook. Every month, they put a notification on each Page that says:

> Posting new content on Page Name is a great way to connect with people who are interested in your Page...

This is extremely annoying because they tell me this exact same thing several times every month, and it results in a notification on my phone.

I want to turn these notifications off, so that it will only alert me when something important happens like I get a message from a real person.

Is there a way to do that?

I have looked at the settings on both desktop Facebook and the Pages app. The notification settings cover user interactions with the page, not Facebook's interactions with the page. Is there a setting for "Turn off Facebook Page tips"? Not that I see.

I have also found [this question](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10214361093491953) on Facebook's advertiser help center, but there are no responses there.

[image: Examples]

Comment: @pnuts see my edits above - I have looked at the settings on both desktop Facebook and the Pages app. The notification settings cover user interactions with the page, not Facebook's interactions with the page.

Answer (score 2):

A possible indirect solution would be to utilize [Facebook's business manager](https://business.facebook.com/). It allows you to add pages and do page management through the business manager portal as opposed to your personal account. You could then remove yourself from the page and you would get notifications in Business Manager only. I do this for several pages I manage so I don't have to deal with it on my actual Facebook account.

Comment: But does it still post the "Posting new content" notifications if business manager is used?

Comment: No, it's not possible to remove it. I looked up your page it has no content so obviously, Facebook is going to poke you to post content.

The correct way within the realm of Facebook (who wants people to post) is to post content.

The answer posted here makes sense since at least the notifications are pushed to users assigned to Business Manager and not your personal Facebook account.  @jaycer

Answer (score 0):

From desktop version, on Notifications Settings page, edit notifications for Pages you manage and set them to "Digest" (see image below). Hopefully this will help you!

[image: Facebook Notifications]

Comment: I will try this - I hope it works!

Comment: Eh, I had Digest turned on, but I just got a “Sharing a photo or post right from your phone...” spam / tip / notification.

Answer (score 0):

**N.B.** The following solution works for browsing Facebook on a desktop browser only. I realise you are asking about the mobile version in this case, but I am sure there are lots of people who will find this information useful anyway.

You can hide specific notification types such as this, with Custom CSS code. For example, these specific Notification types should be able to be hidden using the following instructions:

1. First install the [**FB Purity browser add-on**](http://www.fbpurity.com), that lets you add Custom CSS code to Facebook pages.
2. Once **FB Purity** is installed,  click the "**FBP**" link in the top
   navigation bar of any Facebook page, to open the FBP options screen.
3. Click the "**CSS**" link at the top right of the options screen
4. Copy and paste the following CSS code into the CSS box.

   */* Hide the notifications containing tips about how to increase Page likes  */
   #fbNotificationsFlyout li[data-gt*='"notif_type":"aymt'], div[data-gt="{\"ref\":\"notif_page\"}"] li[data-gt*='"notif_type":"aymt'], #fbNotificationsFlyout li[data-gt*='"notif_type":"page_fan_growth'], div[data-gt="{\"ref\":\"notif_page\"}"] li[data-gt*='"notif_type":"page_fan_growth'] {display: none}*
5. Click the "**Save & Close**" button at the bottom of the FBP options screen.

After that you should now not see those types of notifications anymore in your desktop browser when you are on the Facebook website.

There are further examples of CSS code for hiding other Facebook Notification types on the [**CSS page on FBPURITY.COM**](http://css.fbpurity.com)